# Fixing Markdown styling in Notepad++

Tags: styles, notepad++, markdown

I've got Markdown styles for Notepad++ from [this guy](https://github.com/thomsmits/markdown_npp). They look very well, and the only, quite annoying, thing I found in them, is that bold (`**` or `__`) and italics (`*` or `_`) delimiters "works" also, when used inside words. And styler / Notepad ++ does not seek for ending delimiter once, it find opening one.

So, for example, writing something like this:`We have to use MANY_MANY relation here` causes entire rest of document to be displayed in italics, because `_` char in `MANY_MANY` is taken as starting delimiter for italics (though it is inside a word) and styler / Notepad++ does not seeks for an ending one.

Is there an easy way to workaround this problem or does anyone knows "better" Markdown styles for Notepad++, that does not fall with similar problem? I've heard something, that Notepad++'s styler is a little bit "tough" and problems like above may be impossible to fix. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fork of the one you use at https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown_npp_zenburn

I just checked and it handles the `*`and `_` in the middle of words. Try it out and see if you like it better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to accept your answer, though (as you may see [in here](https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown_npp_zenburn/issues/5)), solution you're referring to is far from perfection (it is even far from original work), so I'm not going to use it. It seems that the guy, who forked original repo, with removal of `_` and `*` from middle of words had removed many of original functionality as well.

Comment: Ok, I never really used it that much myself. Somebody should make a new one combining the best features from the two :-)

Comment: Coming back from 2013. I'm the Edditoria and most problem/bugs are fixed. There are 2 limitations stated in README. Please report in Issue or Push Request if you find any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of UDL and I can confirm that UDL version 2.X can't handle this. If you define delimiter start as `_`, than every single `_` char will trigger delimiter coloring. No exceptions!

Good news is that this feature was already requested by users, and it will be part of UDL 3.0 release. In fact I already implemented it few weeks ago.

Comment: Loreia, thanks for the answer. I've re-edited it to fit SO standards. And just a side note for other readers: `UDL` stands for `User Defined Language`, an "engine" used in Notepad++ to render lexer / language specific coloring & formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The "Edditoria" GitHub repository has a number of bugs (for example, `#` inside a link is broken) and hasn't been updated in years. After trying out the most active forks, [this one](https://github.com/Hyzual/markdown_npp) is much better.

Comment: I'm the Edditoria. This repo is active again :) Most problem/bugs are fixed. There are 2 limitations stated in README. Please report in Issue or Push Request if you find any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are more fundamental issues related to Markdown than Notepad++ regarding `_`. See [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/).