# Spaces in the beginning of line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, whitespace, space

I have opened a simple text file in Notepad++ and "iterated" through all languages' styles available in my `Language` menu. I noticed, that after applying some of them, text displays spaces in the beginning of some lines (left margin), while in other language formatting all this spaces are gone and each line starts with a character next to left margin.

Does anyone know, where in `User Defined Language` window is an option responsible for that? Or which *language styler* (XML file) parameter controls this?

**EDIT**: I have Notepad++ `6.5.1` and I found spaces, when using `Javascript`, `Pascal` and `Resource file`. I also found it in non-standard `Markdown` styling, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20323915/1469208). Example:

[image]

I don't like spaces in the beginning of lines, so I would like to remove them from all my languages / styles, but I don't know which param / option is responsible for that.

Comment: I iterated through all Languages included in Notepad++ v6.5.1, and I didn't found a single one trimming leading spaces in the beginning of lines. Could you please let us know which language did you tried?

Comment: Isn't this a `SuperUser` question?

Comment: @psxls (I do have Notepad++ `6.5.1`) Sure! As for standard (built-in) styles,  I found it in `Javascript`, `Pascal` and `Resource file`. I also found it in non-standard `Markdown` styling, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20323915/1469208), which I'm using the most (updated question with screenshot as a kind of proof).

Comment: @PankajJaju You're free to flag this question as requiring migration. But I've seen similar number of questions about Notepad++ in both SO and SU, so I've choosen SO, as visited by more people! :]

Comment: @trejder That's strange because for example JavaScript language shouldn't remove whitespaces, and I can't reproduce it! Can you please also share with us a minimal text sample with which you get this effect?

Comment: @psxls I see spaces in virtually every document I've been editing for past 3 weeks (since I started using Notepad++). The difference is, that when set to `Javascript` (build-in), I'm getting spaces in fewer lines, than when set to `Markdown` (custom). Sample: `5. If your change will be approved (either by you or someone else), Gerrit should auto-merge it. If it fails on that (because, for example, it is binded to some abandoned change,`. On my 1680x1050 and Notepad++ window maximized, line breaks between of `it` and `is` (in `for example, it is`) and that space appears by the left margin.

Comment: @trejder OK now I see! I'll try to answer to your question.

Comment: @George Stocker: Have you ever run into [this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75909/189165)? Can you please, kindly explain me, what is the reason for _closing_ a question with comment "Seek help at Super User", instead of actually **migrate** it there?

Comment: @trejder It already has an accepted answer; not sure they would want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have `Word wrap` enabled (from `View` menu). So the spaces "in the beginning of some lines" that you are referring to, is the space between two words of your sentence, that depending on the language, the lexer decides whether to move it in the next row or not.

So this doesn't actually remove the spaces, it's just a matter of visualization. If you remove the `Word wrap` option, the spaces are still there.

Now, to achieve this result to each of your documents, the only thing to do is to NOT apply any language style or to be more precise, to select `Normal Text` language from the Language menu, as shown in below screenshot (which actually makes sense since from your screenshot it seems that you are editing simple text files). In addition go to `Settings` > `Preferences...` > `New Document` and in the `Default language` and make sure that you have `Normal Text` selected.

[image]

Comment: So... If I'm getting you right, you mean that **every** language setting, _except_ `Normal Text` displays spaces as a first character of line. I only had a strange lucky / run into twixed coincidence, that I didn't seen them for some languages? Am I getting you right?

Comment: No! *Some* languages, as for example `MS Ini`, or your custom Markup, display the space in the end of the previous line, as `Normal Text` do. So it's not a property of `Normal Text` only. But, this isn't an option that you can enable. I believe this has to do with the lexer of each language (but I'm not able to answer this with certainty). And it seems that the default behavior, which you can see when `Normal Text` is selected (which doesn't have any styles, any keywords etc), do exactly what you want when word wrapping.

Comment: My custom markup (`Markdown`) is **not** following `Normal Text` and **it is** displaying spaces in the beginning of lines. Which actually drives me crazy! :] But, I get your point. Thank you! :] I may only add, with 99,99% certainty, that this is Notepad++'s case, not Scintilla's. As I've been using another editor, based on Scintilla, and it hasn't been showing spaces in the beginning of lines, no matter, what language / lexer was selected.